# Django ImageField ( Image does not display )

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to built a CMS for the admin where he is able to change the images.
But so far it doesn't work and I can't find the error.

Here is the model and there is no default.png

**models.py**

```
class Media(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Photo"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.name
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

print(MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**views.py**

```
def gallery_view(request):
   return render(request, 'web/gallery.html', context={"pic": Media.objects.first()})
```

Here is my **template** for the `ImageField`:

```
<img class="ui bordered image" src="{{ pic.image.url }}">
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('webpage/', include('webpage.urls')),
    path('', include('web.urls')),
    path(r'^', include('web.urls', namespace='web')),
]


urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Now when I `print(MEDIA_ROOT)` my terminal shows this:

```
'Not Found: /media/default.png'

"GET /media/default.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1808"
```

and

```
"POST /admin/web/media/add/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0"

"GET /admin/web/media/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1282"
```

Does anyone have a suggestion for me where the bug is?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your print statements suggest, default.png is not found in your media folder. Have you tried making sure that image is being saved in the media folder?

Comment: It is in the media folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Media(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Give a default value for you models

```
image = models.Imagefield(blank =True, null=True, default ="add photo")
```

Makemigrations and migrate  after adding default.

Not so sure for views

```
def gallery_view(request):
 if(request.method=='POST'):
    = request.POST['media']
   value = 'Media : %s (media)
 return render(request, 'web/gallery.html', context={"pic": Media.objects.first()})
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check if you have added paths for both Static and Media URL in settings.py.
For Static URL:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

For Media URL:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

To access display your img:

```
 <img class="border-radius-50 profile-img" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{  pic.image.url }}" alt="...">
```

Comment: Thx for your suggestion but it didn't solve the problem.